# Which of these vegetables are less bloating?

Tags: nutrition, vegetarianism, vegetable, bloated-bloating

Which should we prefer to feel less bloated: kale, cabbage, spinach, brussels sprout, celery, or avocado? 
Is there a bloating scale for them ?

Comment: None of them make me feel bloated, so how would we construct such a scale?

Comment: @Carey Gregory even cabbage ? It's undeniable fact that it gives people a lot of gas.

Comment: Nope, not even cabbage. It doesn't give me gas or at least not enough that I've ever noticed it. About the only food that does is beans, and that just produces flatulence, not bloating.

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of bloating is consumption of high amount of **soluble fiber,** which is fermentable by normal intestinal bacteria, which produce gas. From your list, Brussels's sprouts and avocado have more soluble fiber than kale, spinach and cabbage.

Other examples of foods high in soluble fiber (potentially bloating):

- Legumes: beans, peas, lentils
- Fruits: figs, eggplant, apples, pears
- Cereals: barley, oats, rye
- Artichokes
- Sweet potatoes

Source: [Nutrientsreview.com](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/carbs/dietary-fiber-soluble-insoluble.html)

Individuals with fructose malabsorption (which is relatively common) can experience bloating after eating foods that contain more **fructose** that glucose (apples, pears, honey, beverages sweetened by HFCS, commercial foods with added "fructo-oligosccarrcharids (FOS)," inulin or sugar alcohols (sorbitol, mannitol, xylitol...).

Source: [Uwhealth.org](https://www.uwhealth.org/healthfacts/nutrition/376.pdf)

Comment: It's not only fiber, there are also sugars that mammals cannot digest.

Comment: The "sugars" that humans cannot digest or absorb are sugar alcohols (polyols) and certain artificial sweetners, such as lactulose. These substances may or may not cause bloating; they more likely cause it in individuals with fructose malabsorption, as mentioned above.

Comment: I meant that a lot of gases being produced if mammals eat such stuff like pea (I'm not sure what term I should use: meteorism, flattulence...)